# Karaf - bundles starting and stopping randomly

Tags: java, apache-karaf, karaf

In Karaf (on Windows only) we have this problem where our bundles are starting and stopping randomly and somewhat strangely. Nothing is shown when we issue **bundle:diag**

So the bundles seem to initially deploy OK (when we install the feature containing them), then we issue **bundle:list** repeatedly and we keep issuing it. And then we see how previously successfully deployed bundles show up suddenly as "Starting" then as "Active" again and so on.

The behavior seems rather random (but OK, it may be circular too, not sure), chaotic, and sporadic too 
(i.e. sometimes that whole thing doesn't happen, sometimes it does).

This is on Windows only. So Karaf on Windows seems somewhat flaky.

I tried googling but no much luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If it happen without your bundle(s) installed, you should report the issue in [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF)

If it only happens with your bundles, then you need to check what exactly your bundles are doing. Keep in mind OSGi (and thus Karaf) will re-resolve when something changes. For example if for whatever reason one of your bundles is stopped, it may stop many more bundles that depend on it. Once the bundle starts again it will automatically start those who have satisfied dependencies.

You didn't provide enough information to be able to closely identify the issue but as this only happens on Windows I'd assume one (or more) of your bundles tries to do something that fails on Windows (probably in the activator) and this somehow triggers re-resolve loop.

Comment: The bundles are just providing REST services. So they just stay there and expect requests to come in. We don't do anything special in them at startup. And yeah, I am aware I didn't post enough info, I just couldn't quite figure out what to post. What information could I possibly post here so that I get some better answers?

Comment: Perhaps they depend on other bundles that are being restarted. You need to monitor the bundles lifecycle and try to pinpoint the initial cause. I'd start by looking at Karaf's log to see which bundles got restarted first.